# write raw query for between in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I have a query scope in laravel and I have a column named `km` which is `varchar`. Now I want to write a raw query scope for it. The problem is it wont search for the `varchar`. So need to cast km to unsigned.

Query -:

```
Product::km($kmFrom, $kmTo);
```

Query scope

```
public function scopeKm($query, $kmFrom, $kmTo)
{   
    $kmFrom = (int)$kmFrom;
    $kmTo = (int)$kmTo;

    if((count($kmFrom) > 0) && count($kmTo) > 0){ 

        return $query->whereBetween('km', [$kmFrom, $kmTo]);   
    }
    return $query;
}
```

I want to write the db raw query for the above in which I cast the `km` column to unsigned in the raw query.

Answer (score 0):

you can write raw queries doing something like this:

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax for using raw query

```
 $result_1 = DB::table('tablename')->whereRaw("column name =".$variable)->select('name','improve','email',DB::raw("DATEDIFF('2016-11-10' , `age`) / 365.25 as age"),'age as dob')->first();
```

or if want complete raw then

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM tablename where 1);
```

hope it will help you!